# Git Credential Manager is using IE but I want it to use Edge

Tags: git-for-windows

I created a new Windows Server 2022 VM, installed all pending updates, then installed the latest versions of Office 365 and Visual Studio 2022.

Edge is already the system default browser:

[image: Edge is the default browser]

When I try to clone a repo from Azure DevOps, the Git Credential Manager window pops up using IE as its browser:

[image: GCM window with IE error message]

IE is no good because it doesn't display the login page correctly. How can I force GCM to use Edge?

I tried this from Git for Windows on the command line and from Visual Studio, but it made no difference.

I tried this with no `.gitconfig` file (default behaviour), and with an explicit minimal `.gitconfig` file, but it made no difference.

```
[user]
    name = <me>
    email = <me>
[credential]
    helper = 
    helper = manager
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
    usehttppath = true
```

Answer (score 8):

You can force git to use your OS system browser default by using credentail.msauthFlow=system

```
git config --local credential.msauthFlow system
```

This was confirmed on Windows Server 2019. The documentation can be found at the link below. Make sure you have uninstalled IE first or set the default web browser app to anything else before using this. Simply setting the default browser will not work as the IE web view will

https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#credentialmsauthflow

Comment: Thanks very much Josiah, sorry for the late reply. I will try that when I next create a new VM, and let you know how it went. :-)

Comment: I think most of the time, people will prefer to always use the same setting. Replace --local with --global like below.
git config --global credential.msauthFlow system

Comment: Totally works - thank you!